# How to make a function that adds a sublist to a list

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, sublist

I want to create a `NewList` of values (between 1 and 0) using a function that adds a `sublist` of values `(low_phase=[0] x 30)` to a second list `(high_phase=[1] x 960 elements long)`. I need a loop because the function needs to go through all elements in time, and I need an if function, that checks when the elements in time are equal to the ones of the list interval, and only then apply the `sublist` low_phase. When the values are equal the list should contain 0, when the values are different, then 1.

```
#this is the `NewList` I want to create. It has to contain values of 1 or 0, which are assigned based on the function with loop 

NewList = []

#this is the first list 
time = list(range(1,960))
#this is the second list 
interval= list(range(60,960,60))

#these are the values to be assigned to the newLIst if the condition is true
high_phase = [1]*960
#these are the values to be assigned to the newLIst if the condition is False
low_phase = [0]*29


def method(NewList):
    for n,m in zip(time,interval):
        if time[n] == interval[m]:
            NewList.extend(low_phase)
        else:
            NewList.append(high_phase)
print(NewList)
```

> example of output: for every time that interval (60, 120, 180 etc) is contained in time (0-960), add a list of 30 values = 0 to NewList, otherwise add 1 to NewList.
> =================

```
     time   interval    NewList
     ...                    1
      58                    1
      59                    1
      60        60          0
      61                    0
      62                    0
     ...                    0
      90                    1
      91                    1
      92                    1
     ....                   1
     120       120          0
     121                    0
     122                    0
     ...                    0
     150                    1
```

Comment: You `zip` two different-sized lists (960 vs. 15 elements). Do you want to iterate the `time` list in slices given by `interval`? Do you want to insert an element from `low_phase` each time an interval ends and otherwise elements from `high_phase`?

Comment: Hi! Yes to the second part. I want to add an element (low_phase, so 30 times 0) each 60 min of time (at interval I chose) and otherwise elements from high_phase.

Comment: at the moment I get the following error: if 'time[n] == interval[m]':
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I am still not sure I understand what you want. Please provide an example input/output, let's say for a time list with 30 entries and intervals of 5 or similar

Comment: @tobias_k I added the example, I hope now I am more understandable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think now I got what you want: A list of 960 `1`s with ranges of 30 `0`s starting at each of the intervals. And that's exactly how you can do it: start with `960*[1]` and replace slices of 30 elements with `30*[0]` for each of the intervals.

```
result = [1] * 960
for i in range(60, 960, 60):
    result[i:i+30] = [0] * 30
```

(Note: In case the last slice of 30 elements is longer than the list, this will extend the list with a few more 0, so you may have to truncate it back to 960 elements at the end.)

Output (some):

```
>>> list(enumerate(result))
[...
 (58, 1),
 (59, 1),
 (60, 0),
 (61, 0),
 (62, 0),
 ...
 (88, 0),
 (89, 0),
 (90, 1),
 (91, 1),
 (92, 1),
 ...]
```

About your original `method` function: There were a number of problems. First, you zipped two list with vastly different length (960 vs. 15 elements), so you will only get the first 15 elements from both. Then, `n` and `m` are already the elements from that list, but with `time[n] == interval[m]` you treat them as indices, which will give an IndexError as the first interval `60` is already larger than the entire list of intervals. Regardless of that, the condition can never be true since intervals start at a higher value and the numbers rise faster, thus the "paired" values can never be equal.

Comment: thank you! now it works! and I kind of understand what the problem was in the function. Very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you provided, I *think* this is what you want:

```
NewList = []

time = list(range(1,960))
interval= list(range(60,960,60))

high_phase = [1]*960
low_phase = [0]*59

def method(NewList):
    for i in interval:
       NewList.extend(low_phase)  # 59 entries from low_phase
       NewList.append(high_phase[len(NewList)])  # matching high_phase entry
    return NewList
            
print(method(NewList))
```

Output (wrapped, truncated)

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, ... 0, 0, 0, 1, 
 0, 0, 0, 0, ... 0, 0, 0, 1, 
 0, 0, 0, 0, ... 0, 0, 0, 1, 
 0, 0, 0, 0, ... 0, 0, 0, 1, 
 0, 0, 0, 0, ... 0, 0, 0, 1, 
 ...........
 0, 0, 0, 0, ... 0, 0, 0, 1, 
 0, 0, 0, 0, ... 0, 0, 0, 1, 
 0, 0, 0, 0, ... 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Comment: thank you for your comment. I was not very clear, but your output is very close to what I want to achieve. I  added an example to the sample code. I